# How to make ListView not respond (change background) on touch?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView which displays some inert items, so this should not change their backgrounds when a user touches the list view or item. This turns out hard to do:
What i have tried so far:
Java:

```
listView.setLongClickable(false);
listView.setClickable(false);
listView.setFocusable(false);
```

This has no effect what so ever. If I touch listview the background changes.

In the xml I tried;

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@null" />
```

Setting listSelector to @null is something I saw elsewehere on stack overflow. Does not work.

I also tried setting each item's background in code to transparent.

```
convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
```

Nothing. On every touch there is always a change in background to blue.
How to make my listview not change item background on touch?

Comment: @Olayinka: ___________________No.

Comment: Could a downwoter please explain the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This,  It works For  Me

```
<ListView 
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Comment: android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" works. Yet I would like to see some confirmation that this is the official way to do it. android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" should not be used lightly as this turns off some optimization. In lack of better answer I will accept this one. The rest of the answers are uneducated gueeses and should be downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `view.setEnabled(false);` in your Adapter getView() - it will remove background effects.

Comment: As stated above I have set my item's background to transparent.

Comment: @f470071  Yes, but you asked how to make ListView items unresponsive, not how to trick them to be invisibly responsive.

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to make a custom background for the listview like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"  />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
       android:drawable="@android:color/white"  />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
       android:drawable="@android:color/white"  />
    </selector>
```

place this xml file with name listbg.xml inside your drawable folder

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listt"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/listbg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@null" />
```

Comment: @f470071 why it's wrong?you can't go with this for a default listview android:id/list go for your own listview like  android:id="@+id/listt"

Comment: what do you have in your listview can you show a screenshot changing it to customlist won't do any harm

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a layout for your list items that has a background which has a different selected state.

See what layout you use for the list items and change that to not include that background. If you are using the default (`android.R.layout.simple_list_item`) layout, you can create and use your own layout.

Comment: As stated above I have set this background to transparent.

Comment: you have set the listview's background. You must do that to the listview's ITEM layout

Comment: As stated above I have set this background to transparent.

Comment: It could be that you had a TexView in your item's layout with a selector as background which had `android:state_activated` to some background color. If you dont post all the code necessary for an answer the best we can do is guess what could be the issue. In your case it was the `android:listSelector` but it COULD be other things.